# Xcode animation from URLS instead of local files

Tags: xcode, image, url, animation, imageview

I am trying to make an animation from some URLS.

I know the code

```
animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"img-1.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"img-2.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"img-3.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"img-4.gif"],nil];
[animation setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
animation.animationDuration = 2;
[animation startAnimating];
```

But how do I load multi pictures from a server and make them animate?
I have an Image View named animation
Can anyone help me out with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here' what I Used For mine

I did mine in my `viewDidLoad` method

```
//use your URL
NSData *picOne = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sumptin.com/images/sumptin.jpg"]];
NSData *picTwo = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sumptin.com/images/sumptin.jpg"]];
NSData *picThree = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sumptin.com/images/sumptin.jpg"]];
NSData *picFour = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sumptin.com/images/sumptin.jpg"]];
NSData *picFive = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sumptin.com/images/sumptin.jpg"]];

//then convert data to actual pictures  
UIImage *onePic = [UIImage imageWithData:picOne];
UIImage *twoPic = [UIImage imageWithData:picTwo];
UIImage *threePic = [UIImage imageWithData:picThree];
UIImage *fourPic = [UIImage imageWithData:picFour];
UIImage *fivePic = [UIImage imageWithData:picFive];

//then SHABAM!
 slideShow.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             onePic,
                             twoPic,
                             threePic,
                             fourPic,
                             fivePic,
                             nil];
slideShow.animationDuration = 60.00f;
slideShow.animationRepeatCount = 0;

[slideShow startAnimating];
```

Hope This Helps...seeing as this question was posted a year ago :)